# Storing a boolean expression into a new variable

Tags: python

I am curious to why I do not get this to work.

*I am curious, why can it NOT return True at all?*

Doesn't this type of logic work in Python, at the return level?

**My code:**

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import os

def output_username(username): 
    if print(username): 
        return True 
    return False 

def output_score(score): 
    if print(score): 
        return True 
    return False 

def output_stats(stats):
    if print(stats): 
        return True
    return False 


def run(): 
    return ((output_username("Username")) and 
            (output_score("Score")) and (output_stats("Stats"))) 


def main(): 
    if(run()):
        print("Yes, they all did run!")
    else: 
        print("No, they failed!")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `print` function always returns `None` which is falsy.  So

```
def func():
    if print(...):
        return True
    return False
```

will always return `False`.

Comment: Thx, so what would be a better way?

Comment: @JessicaWeinel -- I think it really depends on what you're trying to _do_.  You haven't really specified that in the question as far as I can tell ...